# Is it possible for Redis Cluster to have over 256TB capacity?

Tags: memory-management, redis, 64-bit

I'm studying Redis, not gonna construct Redis cluster that uses more than 256TB though,

I'm just curious about the question that i put in the title.

I think it is impossible to use more than 256TB, because current OSs use 64 bit address system. (actually, 64 bit address system uses only 48 bit so 2^48 bytes = 256TBs)
Anyway i'm telling that redis can scale out by generating cluster but it has certain limitation.

You guys, how do you think about it?? please give me your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. Redis cluster is not hosted on a single OS, thus not bounded by the limit you are talking about.

Comment: But how to access If an application layer sees a Redis cluster as one DB? the application is hosted on a single OS.

Comment: @HalimKim The application retrieves data they care and doesn't have to store all of them. Just like your PC can view the almost unlimited amount of information on Internet.